# mock in kotlin multiplateform (both java and js)

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin, mocking

I'm currently converting a kotlin project into a multiplateform build.

an issue is that a lot of test have mock
And all the mock lib are in java only (mockito, mockk)

Do you know any lib who allow mock in kotlin, but for both js and java?